# Is this an F# 2.0 parser bug?

Tags: parsing, compiler-errors, f#, compiler-bug

Microsoft (R) F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1

I'm trying to define new record type:

```
type TestOptions =
   { perRunGC : bool;
     collectGCStat : bool;
   }
```

All is fine, but let's add one more field:

```
type TestOptions =
   { perRunGC : bool;
     collectGCStat : bool;
     highPriority : bool;
   }               ^
```

And I am getting parser error in a position marked above:

```
error FS0010: Unexpected character ' ' in field declaration
```

What's wrong with my code? Is it compiler bug?

Comment: Compiles fine for me. Do you perhaps have a non-breaking space in your source file (which somehow got converted to a regular space when pasting it here)?

Comment: @sepp2k, oh, just removed the space and typed again - works fine! please, add the answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Errors like this are often caused by unicode characters in your source file.

In this case you probably have a non-breaking space (or any other kind of special space) instead of a regular space at the location where the compiler chokes.

Comment: The code was copied from the blog that uses `SyntaxHighlighter` js script to highlight F# source code. Double click on code snippet turn the snippet into `<textarea>` and pre-selects all the code. To workaround the problem, just select the whole code manually, without using double click feature.